# Detect the rails zeus start complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, zeus

I have 2 terminals running, and I'd like to run

```
#on term1
zeus start
#on term2
zeus server
```

The problem is that normally it should wait for the start process to complete.
My question is how could I make the second terminal to *auto start* the server after the `zeus start` complete?

I've tried `sleep 2` ...but there should be **better** way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is something else than a hacky way for this. As stated in [zeus's roadmap](https://github.com/burke/zeus/wiki/Roadmap), starting the server whithout having to start zeus before is planned for version 2...
If you want a hacky way, you can play with a little shell script like the following:

```
while [[ "`ps aux | grep "zeus slave" | wc -l`" == "1" ]]; do sleep 1; done; zeus server
```